# Aplicativo Dá Crash ao Receber Push Notification

Tags: android, apache-cordova

O aplicativo está dando crash, parando, quando recebo uma notificação push.
Isso está acontecendo no Android 8.0 (Oreo) ou superior.

Eu vi que mudou uma política, mas não estou conseguindo corrigir no meu código.
Estou usando o plugin *phonegap-plugin-push* na versão *1.9.1*.

Ele dá o seguindo erro ao receber o push:

> Unable do start receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE...}

Meu **config.xml** do Cordova está assim dentre outras coisas:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.9.2">
   <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="#"/>
</plugin>
```

E meu **AndroidManifest.xml** gerado no momento do build está assim:

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService" />
```

Comment: Bom não entendo de cordova masss, a partir do Android 8 tem varias restrições para iniciar serviços em segundo plano, a grosso modo se o app não está em primeiro plano e for chamado startService() você vai tomar uma exceção. Sugiro dar uma olhada nesta restrição, o erro me parece estar relacionado com isso

Comment: É bem isso mesmo que parece. Mas não sei resolver.

Comment: Bom como envolve cordova não vou conseguir ajudar, mas vou deixar dois links de quando passei por algo parecido e me ajudaram, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110489/background-service-for-android-oreo e https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c

Comment: Então, o problema é que é um plugin de terceiro. Não sei em qual lugar devo alterar o código. Talvez dê pra resolver com algumas variáveis no **config.xml**. Tentei alguns que encontrei, mas nenhum deu certo.